# A more private, local version of Facebook with posts, gallery and maybe even 'on this day' features

Tags: information-management, gallery

A more private, local version of Facebook.

I like Facebook, but it posses security risks, for example: who knows who is looking at things like photos of your children and family and how they're using and where they're sending that info?

I would like a personal local version of Facebook that allows me to:

1. Post items and have them arranged by date in a timeline.
2. View my photo gallery with the photos arranged by date.  It would also be cool to be able to see posts arranged on a calendar.

and

3. Possibly an 'on this day' feature that allows me to see posts or photos on that day in history.

Does anyone have any ideas of software or a combination of software to use?

I am on a Windows PC, but Mac is an option one day.  The software needn't have mobile / tablet versions, though that would be nice.  I would like for there to be a local-only version if possible rather than using the cloud, though a "private-cloud" could be an option.

It would also be cool, though not necessary, to have a semi-public version of the app to share things only among family members or friends.

I know that these ideas are things that several people have been looking into lately.

Comment: I would guess that a lot of, perhaps most, note-taking programs would provide (1) and (2). (3) is an entirely different sort of thing and is probably best met by looking at, say, Wikipedia's "On this day" feature. Unless you meant your personal history, in which case you could just view whatever date you want to through the program's ordinary interface.

Comment: Thank for your suggestions.  I will look into Wiki software and continue looking into other options.

Comment: I would like to see all of my items on a horizontal timeline rather than vertical and sorted by date; so personal photos and documents (logs, agendas, and 'what I did on this day') and thumbnail previews of news articles and books on Amazon.